# I made an Employee Data Management System (EDMS) but everytime I need to update employee information it doesn't work

Tags: python, python-3.x

I made this program and it works for the most part but everytime I go to delete an employee or update employee detail, it shows employeeID doesn't exist even though I have added it.
Additional information would be that I am using Pycharm.
Any help would be aprreciated.
I have tried doing it by adding many different employees it is just not working.

```
1 to Add Employee
2 to Delete Employee
3 to Update Employee
4 to Display Employees
5 to Exit
Enter your Choice:2
Enter employee ID to delete: 10001
Employee with ID 10001 does not exist.
```

```
import datetime
import pickle
import os

def addEmployee():
    fullName = input("Enter full name: ")
    employeeID = int(input("Enter employee ID: "))
    department = input("Enter department: ")
    doj = input("Enter date of joining (MM/DD/YYYY): ")
    salary = int(input("Enter annual salary: "))

    if len(fullName) == 0:
        print("Please enter full name.")
        return

    if not 10000 <= employeeID <= 99999:
        print("Employee ID should be in the range of 10000 and 99999.")
        return

    if department not in ["Marketing", "Finance", "Human Resource", "Technical"]:
        print("Department should be Marketing, Finance, Human Resource, or Technical.")
        return

    try:
        datetime.datetime.strptime(doj, "%m/%d/%Y")
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid date of joining format.")
        return

    if not 30000 <= salary <= 200000:
        print("Salary should be in the range of 30000 and 200000.")
        return
    
    if os.path.exists("employees.pkl") == False:
        employees = []
        with open("employees.pkl", "wb") as f:
            pickle.dump(employees, f)
            
    with open("employees.pkl", "rb") as f:
        employees = pickle.load(f)
        if employeeID in employees:
            print("Employee with ID1 {} already exists.".format(employeeID))
            return

    employees.append({
        "fullName": fullName,
        "employeeID": employeeID,
        "department": department,
        "doj": doj,
        "salary": salary
    })

    with open("employees.pkl", "wb") as f:
        pickle.dump(employees, f)

    print("Employee added successfully.")


def displayEmployees():
    with open("employees.pkl", "rb") as f:
        employees = pickle.load(f)

    if len(employees) == 0:
        print("No employees found.")
        return

    print("Employees:")
    for employee in employees:
        print(employee)


def deleteEmployee():
    employeeID = int(input("Enter employee ID to delete: "))

    with open("employees.pkl", "rb") as f:
        employees = pickle.load(f)
        if employeeID not in employees:
            print("Employee with ID {} does not exist.".format(employeeID))
            return

    employees.remove({"employeeID": employeeID})

    with open("employees.pkl", "wb") as f:
        pickle.dump(employees, f)

    print("Employee deleted successfully.")


def updateEmployee():
    employeeID = int(input("Enter employee ID to update: "))

    with open("employees.pkl", "rb") as f:
        employees = pickle.load(f)
        if employeeID not in employees:
            print("Employee with ID {} does not exist.".format(employeeID))
            return

    updatedSalary = None
    updatedDepartment = None

    print("What do you want to update?")


def menu():
    print("1 to Add Employee")
    print("2 to Delete Employee")
    print("3 to Update Employee")
    print("4 to Display Employees")
    print("5 to Exit")

    ch = int(input("Enter your Choice:"))
    if ch == 1:
        addEmployee()
    elif ch == 2:
        deleteEmployee()
    elif ch == 3:
        updateEmployee()
    elif ch == 4:
        displayEmployees()
    elif ch == 5:
        exit(0)
    else:
        print("Invalid Input")
        menu()
menu()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Key issue**:

The problem is to remember that 'employees' is a dictionary.

**Description**:

So when you load it for updating you have to loop over each item in the dictionary then check if that item['employeeID'] equals the employeeID you're trying to match. Same thing when deleting and employee. You have to loop over each item in the dictionary to check if a matching employeeID is matched, then remove that entire item from the dict.

**Alternative Suggestion**:

Consider switching your employees file to using the employeeID as the dictionary key. For example

```
employees = {10000: {"fullName": fullName,
                     "employeeID": employeeID,
                     "department": department,
                     "doj": doj,
                     "salary": salary
                     }
            }

# check if an employee exists:
employees.get(employeeID, None)

# delete an employee:
del employees[employeeID]

# add an employee
employees[employeeID] = {"fullName": fullName,
                         "employeeID": employeeID,
                         "department": department,
                         "doj": doj,
                         "salary": salary
                         }

# update an employee
employees[employeeID]["salary"] = None
employees[employeeID]["department"] = None
```